# Meaning of a potential in the wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, waves, potential

There a many mathematical publications discussing **wave equations with a potential** in the context of inverse problems (i.e., reconstruction of an unknown potential from observations of the flux or displacement).

What are physical examples of wave equations with a potential $q(x)$,

$$ \partial_{tt}u + c^2\nabla^2 u + q(x)u = f, $$

aside from the Schrödinger equation? How can such a potential be interpreted in the classical theory?

Comment: Excellent definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential

Comment: And as I thought when you think of potential, think of *energy*

Comment: This appears to be a list based question, education is generally considered as *off topic*  as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

For example, think about a rope where $x$ represents each points, and $u(x)$ represents the height of the little portion of the rope at position $x$; most simply, consider a constant case $q(x) = q_0$, then you could take it as a gravitational potential energy, i.e. $q_0 = \rho g$. And of course you could construct other forms of more complicated potential fields.